Express req.body is empty for form base request, but works for json based request
My req.body comes out empty when i send the data using postman with form-data field. But works completely fine when i send data using raw-json field.
//app.js
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
const cookie = require("cookie-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo");
const passport = require("passport");
const dbName = require("./constants.js").DB_Name;

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.CORS_ORIGIN,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "16kb" }));
app.use(require("morgan")("dev"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(cookie());

const sessionStore = MongoStore.create({
  mongoUrl: `${process.env.MONGODB_URL}/${dbName}`,
  collectionName: "sessions",
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.TOKEN_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);

require("./middleware/auth.middleware.js");
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

const { userRouter } = require("./router/user.routes.js");
app.use("/api/v1/auth", userRouter);

module.exports.app = app;


user.controller.js
const User = require("../models/user.model.js");
const ApiError = require("../utils/ApiError.js");
const ApiResponse = require("../utils/ApiResponse.js");
const asyncHandler = require("../utils/asyncHandler.js").asyncHandler;

const sendHello = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send("<h1>Hello</h1>");
});

user.router.js
const Router = require("express").Router;
const sendHello = require("../controller/user.controller.js").sendHello;
const registerUser = require("../controller/user.controller.js").registerUser;

const userRouter = Router();
userRouter.route("/register").post(registerUser);
userRouter.route("/success").post(sendHello);

module.exports.userRouter = userRouter;


asyncHandler.js
const asyncHandler = (requestHandler) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    Promise.resolve(requestHandler(req, res, next))
      .catch((err) => {
        next(err);
      });
  };
};
export { asyncHandler };

Tried to do with creating form and using it to send request it forms perfectly due gives empty list or empty object when using postman. Expecting to get my form data in req.body

Did you tell it to use express.urlencoded?  If not, body will be empty.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-body-property/

Hi, Did the answer below find useful ?

The Content-Type header in requests and response is used to indicate the original media type of a resource in an HTTP content transmission.
On a client side, it is specified either in html forms or in API requests. Example below.
const response = await fetch("https://example.org/post", {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  // .,.
});

On the server side, the same Content-Type plays a vital role while parsing requests. The body parsers loaded in a server
will use this header information to find matching requests. It will parse and create body object only when
Content-Type header in a request matches with the same type configured in the parser.
Please see below the only two middlewares loaded at present in the server. The default Content-Type for each of these
middleware also specified here.
// “application-json”
app.use(express.json()); 
// "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: "16kb" })); 

It means the server will parse any requests with any of the two Content-Types.
The requests other than these two types will now be unhandled from parsing.
Now coming to the specific issue, ‘form-data’ at present  has been handled only in part, it has not been handled fully.
It means form-data, which can come in the following two types.
a) Content-Type in URL-encoded form submission
b) Content-Type in multipart forms :
When form-data does not include file upload, then it can be transmitted in URL-encoded form. The Content-Type in this case
will be application/x-www-form-urlencoded. This shall be handled by the server since it has the parser express.urlencoded already loaded.
However, when form-data includes file upload, then it needs to be transmitted in another content type which is multipart/form-data.
Since this Content-Type is entirely different from URL-encoded, it needs to have another parser in the server.
The middleware - Multer is used in such contexts.
Solution:
a) If the form-data under testing does not include file upload, then please specify content type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the front-end. This will be handled by the parser presently loaded.
b) If the data includes file upload, then please specify ‘enctype’ to multipart-form-data in the front-end.
And load the middleware Multer to handle the same at the server side.
Please see below an MRE - minimal reproducible example, with test results.
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer')({ dest: './uploads' });

const app = express();

app.post('/formsimple', express.urlencoded({ extended: true }), (req, res) => {
  console.log(`Content type: ${req.get('Content-Type')}`);
  console.log(`req.body : ${req.body.key1}`);
  res.send('done');
});

app.post('/formfileupload', multer.any(), (req, res) => {
  console.log('-'.repeat(80));
  console.log(`Content type: ${req.get('Content-Type')}`);
  console.log(`req.body ${req.body.key1}`);
  console.log(req.files);
  res.send('done');
});

const formsimple = new URLSearchParams({ key1: 'value1' });

fetch('http://localhost:3000/formsimple', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formsimple,
  headers: {
    // this is the default content-type
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
});

const formfileupload = new FormData();
formfileupload.set('key1', 'value1');
formfileupload.set('file1', new Blob(['some file content']));

fetch('http://localhost:3000/formfileupload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formfileupload,
  headers: {
    // encryption type is to set instead of content-type
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  },
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

Test resulsts:
Content type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
req.body : value1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Content type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----formdata-undici-011973766153
req.body value1
[
  {
    fieldname: 'file1',
    originalname: 'blob',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
    destination: './uploads',
    filename: '48aa0965ac8f8b251997990a5c33368a',
    path: 'uploads/48aa0965ac8f8b251997990a5c33368a',
    size: 17
  }
]

Citations:
Content-Type
Form-based File Upload in HTML
express.json
